# GitHub Pagesの更新を自動化したい

Tags: github-pages

GitHub Pagesを用いたサイトを運営しています。
Javaを用いて、とあるSteamゲームのleaderboards（順位表）データのxmlを読み込んでそれを元にサイト内のhtmlを作成するコードを書いたので、それを用いてサイトの更新を毎日手動で行っています。
（「Eclipse上でコードを動かしてhtml作成→GitHub Desktopでcommit/pushする」の手順で行っています。）

このまま手動で更新し続けることも不可能ではないでしょうが、可能であれば自動で定期的に更新できるようにしたいと思っています。

自分で調べて何とかしたかったのですが、恥ずかしながら適切な検索ワードすら分からないという状態です。何か良い方法はないでしょうか？「このサイト/この本のここを読めば書いてある。」といった情報でも結構です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

定期的な実行は、"Cron"や"Scheduler"のような命名がなされているクラウドサービスで実現することが可能かと思います。

ただ、GitHub Pages の定期更新を行う目的では、同じく GitHub が提供している [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/ja/actions) の [`schedule`イベント](https://docs.github.com/ja/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events) を利用するのが簡単かと思います。

注意点としては、厳密に更新時刻を守りたい場合には向いていないと思います。

---

私自身、このサービスを利用したことがなかったので今回初めて試してみたのですが、次のような設定で実現できました:

- https://github.com/hello-github-actions/updater/blob/main/.github/workflows/update.yml

作業ログは次になります:

- [GitHub Actions を使って GitHub Pages を定期更新する](https://yukihane.github.io/blog/202106/06/hello-github-actions/)